# Маппинг свойств в spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, pojo

Мне нужно обрабатывать POST запрос в контроллере Spring. Запрос имеет тип `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, который в Spring не поддерживается в качестве RequestBody. Нагуглил вариант:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/directory", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String welcome(DirectoryRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

Здесь DirectoryRequest - мой POJO класс, на который должны маппиться параметры запроса. Отчасти это работает: для полей с простыми названиями типа `domain`, маппинг срабатывает. Но есть поля типа `Event-Date-GMT`, для которых нельзя задать одноименное поле в классе. Как с этим быть?

Comment: Можно вместо `DirectoryRequest` изпользовать `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Можно, но тогда нужно вручную маппить каждое поле, не очень красиво. Мне казалось, это должно быть как-то реализовано уже, по аналогии с jackson

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16520399/6066470

Answer (score 0):

Используйте аннотацию @RequestParam для нужных филдов и клепайте POJO ручками.